# What are benefits and drawbacks of using proxy catching server ?

Tags: caching, proxy, architecture

Can someone with experience in using proxy catch server mention some benefits and drawback of using such architecture? 
Some of our team members are trying to promote using Proxy server in our enterprise application. The application is a kind of an intermediate application that communicates with other systems, to fetch data and act upon this data, instead of directly referring to these systems. 
The picture below depicts the two architectures.

[image]

Comment: What are you going to cache?

Comment: Good question ... But I really don't know what they really want to cache

Comment: Do you even know if the responses from those App servers are even cachable?  E.,g. if there's no ETag, or no Expires, header, then the cache may just get in the way, or worse mean you start dealing with stale data.  It all comes down to what data you expect to be able to cache from those servers, and they have a lot of control over that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything depends on the problem you need to resolve. If things are pretty quick regarding the database server and the application server, then caching into something like Redis might be worth a try. However, if the server is under a lot of pressure, then caching might be needed. For instance if we are talking about a news site with lots of long articles and a lot of comments then it might be worth to generate static HTML files to reduce the pressure, however, there is a cost in the freshness of data. For instance if I write a comment to your article and the article is cached and the cache expires after two days, then I will see something like "your comment is awaiting moderation" for two days unless my change triggers cache refresh. Which is not the best imaginable user-experience. But you can choose to refresh the cache whenever the content has been changed. Also, if you use such caching system, you need to track the cached items individually or in small groups to prevent refreshing all your articles' cache when only one has changed. In this case the app should trigger proxy cache refresh. But then you will have to deal with hacktivists who might be aware that you are using a caching system and would generate a lot of write operations to trigger cache refresh. A minimum cache lifetime setting is to be desired to cope with this situation. But then you pay again in user-experience.

So, the question to answer is:

**Are my technical problems so serious that I need to sacrifice a significant amount of the user-experience to gain performance? If so, what is the desired lifetime length of a cache? How much can I sacrifice from the user-experience?**

If your system is quick, serves the users well and your servers could handle much more pressure, then this is premature optimization and should be avoided. If problems are imminent or you already have a problem, then you need to optimize things. Among the optimization possibilities this approach is a possibility, with its own ups and downs.

Comment: Excellent Answer ... ! What we are trying to catch is a precise data, which I don't think it is a good idea at all.